# CakePHP Duplicate Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I have a pretty large controller where a model and the corresponding views are named according to the naming and file structure convention of CakePHP.

I need to make a very large modification to a page that this controller creates (one of the views) and that's why I wanted to make a duplicate controller so that I won't mess up the original.

What are the steps I need to perform to do this?

I've done:

1. Duplicate the controller and rename the new file accordingly.
2. Change the class name of the new controller accordingly.
3. Duplicate the views and have them on a new folder which is named according to the new controller.
4. Duplicate the model and rename the new file accordingly.
5. Change the class name of the new model accordingly.
6. On the model, add this line so that it uses the correct database model: `public $useTable = 'TableName';`

After doing all these, I still have an error and I can't view the same page using the new controller by modifying the URL. Anyone knows how I can duplicate a page using a different controller?

Comment: 1. what version of cake   2. (and most important), what is the error?

Comment: Take a copy of you `src/` and work on the current files. If you get an error, complare the files or backtrack until you get it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue.

It turns out that I needed to load the new Model through the `beforeFilter` function of the new controller.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->loadModel('OldModel');
}
```